# linq where according to selected item?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, properties, selected

I am new to EF and LINQ, hoping to get some answers here.

I am trying to search from list with where condition that is according to the selecteditem from a combobox.
The combobox has 15 items(all bit datatypes) but let me just narrow it down to 2 for examples sake. items are( pro bono, civil)

Now I have a list called listOfAllNeutrals (object name is Neutral with properties such as pro bono (bit) and civil(bit), and I want to filter it using the where condition according to the selected item.

so if selected item = pro bono, the linq would look like this

```
var result = from n in listOfAllNeutrals 
             where n.probono==true 
             select n;
```

but my prob is how do I tell that the `n.property` should be according to the selecteditem?
like this:

```
var result = from n in listOfAllNeutrals 
             where getpropertyName==true 
             select n;
```

is there a simpler way, I don't want to use If conditions if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use if's or switch inside the getpropertyName(Neutral objNeutral) function to Map the selected item to the property you want to evaluate and evaluate it. You need to map object => property in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var result = from n in listOfAllNeutrals 
             where (selectedItem == proBono && n.probono == true)
             || (selectedItem == civil && n.civil == true)
             select n;
```

Comment: this is okay but I do not want to do that since it is like doing if selecteditem is probon, where n.probo. I came up with the solution like below, where I get the list directly from the db using a keyword accrdg to selected item (QualificationSubType)  NeutralFileMaintList = FileMaintenanceBusiness.Instance.GetManyNeutralFileMaintInfobyKeyword(true, QualificationSubType);

Comment: Ok, I just reread the question and I see that there are 15 items in the combobox, so my solution definitely wouldn't be an elegant one. But let me ask you this, you have 15 columns in the table, one for each item? Are you sure that's the best solution, have you considered doing this in a single column? It would make this query much simpler and you could still make properties for your class in order for the rest of the code to compile and work. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx (scroll to the part called Enumeration Types as Bit Flags) for a simple example

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I think it is better to have these as columns as it will be used often in the whole system and this is per case(thousands of legal cases) not just categorized like in the example in the link. :)